# XML Validation Error in slideMaster in PPTX

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am generating XML for a slideMaster part of a pptx file. When running it through the Open Office Productivity Tool and validating the XML I am getting the following error:

> Inner Exception: '6' is not a valid XSD ID.

What is causing this validation problem?

XML: http://pastebin.com/JPtcVmUj (too large for stackoverflow form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XML attributes declared in XSD to be ID types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#ID) must match the [NCName production](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-NCName) and therefore must begin with a letter:

> ```
> NCName ::= (Letter | '_') (NCNameChar)*
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the information, but where in my document are these "id" types? I did a grep for "id" and did not find anything. For that matter, when I grep for "6" I also do not find anything that looks suspicious.

Comment: Try changing `//a:blip/@r:embed` from `6` to `rId6`.   Don't forget to change to same value on the referent side (`//Relationship/@id`).

Comment: Ah yep, that was the problem. Thank you for  your help.